# What is 'future considerations'?

Tags: ice-hockey, trade

I've seen quite a few trades in the NHL go by as 'Player X for future considerations'.

But what is, actually, future considerations? Is there any obligations to the team that gave 'future considerations' or its just a fancy way of saying 'we traded the player for literally nothing'?

Comment: Great question. Every off season I wonder what "future considerations" means

Comment: IIRC you can't straight up trade players for cash, so it's either minimal picks or players that teams will decide on in the future. Mostly likely a variation of "pick from this list of scrubs or our lowest pick once we finish our offseason trades".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Future considerations is deferring the completion of a trade to a later point in time by sending (a) player(s) and/or (a) pick(s) as [you can't straight up trade players for cash](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/what-is-in-fact-future-considerations/28208#comment37853_28199).

The motivation to do this type of trade is:

- due to not having the assets to trade at the time the trade is initiated
- to reassess the landscape of the team when looking to complete the trade

This [article](https://www.sportingnews.com/us/nhl/news/nhl-future-considerations-explained-hockey-trade/h3egzkoougewz3moiulucwfn#:%7E:text=When%20a%20team%20agrees%20to%20send%20another%20club%20future%20considerations%2C%20it%20means%20that%20at%20another%20point%20in%20time%2C%20they%20will%20complete%20the%20deal%20by%20sending%20either%20a%20player%2C%20a%20pick%20or%20multiple%20of%20either.) goes into more detail:

> When a team agrees to send another club future considerations, it
> means that at another point in time, they will complete the deal by
> sending either a player, a pick or multiple of either.
>
> ...
>
> In the NHL, teams cannot trade a player or draft picks for cash alone,
> so a player or pick has to go back the other way. Oftentimes, a team
> wants to wait and figure out what position they need, or if they want
> to get a draft pick in a later round.

Comment: So basically a later trade will probably be said to be 'the return of this future considerations trade' but I guess I've not been looking closes enough to see.

Comment: That's correct. Unless you're following closely, the attention span toward such trades tends to diminish before the trade is completed.